# what are the benefits of setting a name and thread group for one thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

what are the benefits of setting a `name` and `thread group` for one thread when creating a it in java ? and can I monitor it in `LogCat` (in android) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefit of setting a name is mainly for logging purposes.

The benefit of setting a thread group is so you can use the methods of `ThreadGroup` on it.

Comment: @Bader As I suggested, when you need any of its methods. I suggest you look them up in the Javadoc.

Comment: ThreadGroup was useful before Java 5, mainly because of uncaughtException handler, but after this was added to the Thread class itself, I think ThreadGroup is almost considered deprecated, as there are no useful methods left on there

Answer (score 1):

I would also add that it helps with debugging, in addition to logging - when you look at threads in jstack / jvisualvm it's easier to see what each is.